# Applied mathematics, when to leave out delta function?

Tags: derivatives

I cant figure out when I´m supposed to ignore the $\delta(t)$ function in the answer.

$\theta(t)$ is The Heaviside function

I have three examples:

**1.** Let $f(t) = e^t\theta(t)$ and find $f'$

Answer: $(e^t\theta(t))' = (e^t)'\theta(t) + e^t(\theta(t))' = e^t\theta(t) + e^t\delta(t) = e^t\theta(t) + \delta(t)$

Hence $\delta$(t) stay.

**2.** Let $f(t) = e^{2t}\theta(t)$ and find $f'$

Answer: $(e^{2t}\theta(t))' = (e^{2t})'\theta(t) + e^{2t}(\theta(t))' = 2e^{2t}\theta(t) + e^{2t}\delta(t) = 2e^{2t}\theta(t) + \delta(t)$

Again $\delta(t)$ stays.

**3.** Let $f(t) = t\theta(t)$ and find $f'$

Answer: $(t\theta(t))' = t'\theta(t) + t(\theta(t))' = \theta(t) + t\delta(t) = \theta(t)$

Here $\delta(t)$ is just removed in the last step? Why is it okay to remove it?

(These writings are from an previous exam and I've just entered the answers from the key)

Comment: What is $\theta$? The Heaviside function?

Comment: Yes, exaclty. I should add that. I just know it as the "stepfunction".

Comment: the delta function is $0$ everywhere but at $0$. The function $t$ is $0$ at $0$, hence $t\delta(t)$ is $0$ everywhere

Comment: @DavidEverlöf Actually, "step function" is a better name than "Heaviside function", because it names the function after its properties and not after some obscure guy who used it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). I'm just more used to the other name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(t)\delta(t) = f(0)\delta(t)$

Comment: Hm, guess that makes sense.

Comment: It's easy to prove, remembering that the delta 'function' is only defined through integration (it's a distribution, not a function).

Comment: Fine for me, as long as I understand how to answer the questions.. Thanks